# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0:

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, webview

Trying to create an smart watch application opening a web view which runs some javascript code. I get a crazy:

```
Process: com.example.myapp.smartwatch, PID: 3308
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp.smartwatch/com.example.myapp.smartwatch.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
```

Here is MWE.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.myapp.smartwatch;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.wearable.activity.WearableActivity;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity {

    private WebView webview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Prepare webview: add zoom controls and start zoomed out
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        final WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview.setInitialScale(1);

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // after the HTML page loads, run JS to initialize graph
                int dataset[] = new int[] {5,10,15,20,35};
                String text = Arrays.toString(dataset);

                webview.loadUrl("javascript:initGraph(" + text + ", " +(webview.getHeight()) + ", " + (webview.getWidth()) + ")");
            }
        });

        // Load base html from the assets directory
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/graph.html");
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/dark_grey"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.myapp.smartwatch.MainActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="wear"
    android:padding="@dimen/box_inset_layout_padding">


        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout>
```

And here is the full error I get:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapp.smartwatch, PID: 3308
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp.smartwatch/com.example.myapp.smartwatch.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172)
        at com.example.myapp.smartwatch.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172) 
        at com.example.myapp.smartwatch.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172) 
        at com.example.myapp.smartwatch.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at com.android.webview.nullwebview.NullWebViewFactoryProvider.createWebView(NullWebViewFactoryProvider.java:42)
        at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2272)
        at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2331)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3795)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3898)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:573)
        at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:597)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:542)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:525)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:512)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172) 
        at com.example.myapp.smartwatch.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I have checked other threads about this error but I am in particular confused about this "line 0" on the xml file error. Would anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Wear [does not support `WebView`](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/index.html).

More concretely, examine the original exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.android.webview.nullwebview.NullWebViewFactoryProvider.createWebView(NullWebViewFactoryProvider.java:42)
```

Since Android 4.4 or thereabouts, `WebView` is provided by the "System WebView" app, which means Android has to do some gyrations to get its hand on the guts of `WebView` implementation when you request to display the `WebView`. Here, `NullWebViewFactoryProvider` means "we do not have a System WebView to use".

Comment: Damn! How come I can find web browsers for smart watches then?  Any idea on a workaround in that case?

Comment: would wraping it up in a layout(linear or relative...) solve the problem ?

Comment: @LBes: "Any idea on a workaround in that case? " -- with JavaScript support? No clue, sorry. For rudimentary unstyled HTML, `Html.fromHtml()` and a `TextView` works.

Comment: @CommonsWare accepted your answer! Sorry, it seems that I forgot to do it